# How to stop parent gridview event when click on child control click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have linkbutton in GridView. GridView has client event - rowselect. When I click LinkButton, client event (rowselect) is fired. I want to stop firing rowselect client event when I click LinkButton.

Any solution?

For Example.

GridView has 3 rows, two columns

```
Column 1 ---- Column 2 [LinkButton]
AAAAAA   ---- test.aspx?ID=001
BBBBBB   ---- test.aspx?ID=002
CCCCCC   ---- test.aspx?ID=003

Client Side JavaScript (fired on GridView row selection)
function DisplayData(gridview row)
{
  //get data from selected row.
}
```

If select first column of row, invoke client side event, it is ok. But when click LinkButton, redirect to test.aspx .. no fire on client side event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation to stop event propagation. For older browser which do not support `e.stopPropagation()` you can use `e.cancelBubble = true`

```
document.getElementById("<%= yourRadDatePickerID.ClientID %>").onclick = function(e) {

    if(e && e.stopPropagation ) 
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } 
    else
    {
          e = window.event;
          e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: LinkButton is server control inside GridView cell. in GridView_RowCreated event, nagivate url (parameters) of LinkButton is generated. Client Side, read some data from GridView row selection. When LinkButton is clicked, redirect to other page which is fine. But I don't want Client Side event when LinkButton is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click handler to your `LinkButton` that prevents the event from bubbling.  Use `event.stopPropagation()`.  For older IE browsers, use `event.cancelBubble = true`:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="cancelClick(event)" ... />
```

```
function cancelClick(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```